# Playwright, Node.JS & Cucumber - Artifact is disposed more than once

Tags: node.js, playwright, cucumberjs

I need a bit of help identifying this issue. I don't understand what it means and there's seemingly no help online for this error.

It comes when trying to run my Cucumber-JS, Node.JS & Playwright automation framework; but I don't know what it means.

The full error reads:

```
    ✖ Before # file:///common-hooks.ts:42
        artifact@3c8a31b63beeaf0512fcc8d0407bfeac is disposed more than once

    ✖ After # file:///common-hooks.ts:70
        Attachment (text/plain): Status: FAILED. Duration:3s
        TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'basePage')
            at World.<anonymous> (file:///common-hooks.ts:77:35)
            at file:///common-hooks.ts:7:71
            at __awaiter (file:///common-hooks.ts:3:12)
            at World.<anonymous> (file:///common-hooks.ts:72:12)
```

Which I don't understand what artifact it's talking about or why this failure then triggers the failure in the After step?

I am trying to include Screenshots and Video reporting in my framework, so maybe it's one of those? anyway; here's my hooks (Before's and After's):

```
common-hooks.ts

import "core-js";
import { Before, After, BeforeAll, ITestCaseHookParameter, Status, AfterAll } from "@cucumber/cucumber";
import { ChromiumBrowser, chromium } from "@playwright/test";
import { AllPagesObject } from "../../pages/AllPagesObject.js";
import ICustomWorld from "../../support/custom-world.js";
import config from "../../support/config.js";
import { ensureDir } from "fs-extra";
import { Tools } from "../../support/Tools.js";
import * as cp from "child_process";

let browser: ChromiumBrowser;
const tracesDir = "traces";

declare global {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-namespace
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface Global {
            browser: ChromiumBrowser;
        }
    }
}

BeforeAll(async function () {
    // We need to keep an eye on the following PR as the this World is not recognised by the BeforeAll step: 
    // https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/pull/1770
    browser = await chromium.launch({
        headless: true,
        args: ["--start-fullscreen"],
    });
    await ensureDir(tracesDir);
});

Before({ tags: "@ignore" }, async function () {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
    return "skipped" as any;
});

Before({ tags: "@debug" }, async function (this: ICustomWorld) {
    this.debug = true;
});

Before(async function (this: ICustomWorld, { pickle }: ITestCaseHookParameter) {
    this.tools = new Tools();
    this.homePageURL = this.tools.getUrlByEnvironment([MY-ENV]);
    const email = this.tools.getUsernameByRole("ValidCredentials");
    const password = this.tools.getPasswordByRole("ValidCredentials");
    const clientId = this.tools.getClientIdByEnvironment([MY-ENV]);
    
    try {
        cp.execSync(
            `aws cognito-idp sign-up --client-id=${clientId} --username=${email} --password=${password} --validation-data Name=password,Value=${password}`
        );
    } catch(e) {
        //Do nothing
    }
    this.startTime = new Date();
    this.videoDirectory = "videos";
    this.context = await browser.newContext({recordVideo: config.recordVideos ? { dir: this.videoDirectory } : undefined,});

    await this.context.tracing.start({ screenshots: true, snapshots: true });

    this.page = await this.context.newPage();
    this.pageType = "";
    this.userType = "";
    this.newEmailField = "";
    this.newUsernameField = "";
    this.quidco = new AllPagesObject(this.page, this.context);
    this.startTime = new Date();
    this.testName = pickle.name.replace(/\W/g, "-");
    this.feature = pickle;
});

After(async function (this: ICustomWorld, { result }: ITestCaseHookParameter) {
    if (result) {
        this.attach(`Status: ${result?.status}. Duration:${result.duration?.seconds}s`);

        const formattedTime = this.startTime?.toISOString().split(".")[0] .replace(/:/g, "_");

        if (result.status !== Status.PASSED) {
            await this.quidco.basePage.screenshot(`${this.feature?.name}`);

            // rename video
            const currVideoFilePath = await this.page?.video()?.path();

            if (currVideoFilePath) {
                const currVideoFileName = currVideoFilePath.split('/').pop();
                const newVideoFilePath = `${this.videoDirectory}/${result.status}/${this.testName}_${formattedTime}_${currVideoFileName}`;
                console.log(`Saving video as: ${newVideoFilePath}`);
                this.page?.video()?.saveAs(newVideoFilePath);

                // delete video if possible, do not throw an error otherwise
                try {
                    this.page?.video()?.delete();
                } catch (e) {}
            }
        }

        // rename video
        const currVideoFilePath = await this.page?.video()?.path();

        if (currVideoFilePath) {
            const currVideoFileName = currVideoFilePath.split("/").pop();
            const newVideoFilePath = `${this.videoDirectory}/${result.status}/${this.testName}_${formattedTime}_${currVideoFileName}`;
            console.log(`Saving video as: ${newVideoFilePath}`);
            this.page?.video()?.saveAs(newVideoFilePath);

            // delete video if possible, do not throw an error otherwise
            try {
                this.page?.video()?.delete();
            } catch (e) {}
        }
    }

    await this.context?.clearCookies();
    await this.page?.close();
    await this.context?.close();
});

AfterAll(async function () {
    await browser.close();
});
```